# How to get at TCP RTT on Windows (Linux TCP_INFO) as an user

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, sockets

I am porting a streaming TCP app from Linux to Windows.
The app streams real-time audio data using a preexisting TCP protocol (so switching to UDP isn't an option).  Further, I wish to avoid being "part of the problem" and requiring Administrator rights.

The Linux code uses `getsockopt(... ,SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, ..)` to get the RTT (round trip time) information from the TCP connection. The application level uses this to throttle the amount of data sent over the connection (apparently to balance quality with latency).

Is there an equivalent to TCP_INFO on WIndows?
(google tells me that Win2K and later supports "TCP Timestamps" which would provide this information, but I've yet to find a way to get at it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably won't help so I'm only including it as a comment, but here's what MSDN says about getsockopt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738544(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb485738(VS.85).aspx

Vista apparently has this, which is probably your best bet (that was just a quick google search)